# How to give highest trust level to an OpenPGP certificate in Kleopatra?

Tags: public-key-encryption, gnupg, openpgp

I'd like to give the highest trust level to a certificate. I need to do so, as this certificate is mine but I don't have exported it before formatting my PC.

I have downloaded it from a public key server and I have my private key saved in KeePass, but I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Please have a look at the [FAQ] to get an understanding what kinds of questions are on topic on Stack Overflow. This is not a development question at all, and a much better fit for Stack Overflow's sister site, Super User. I already flagged your question for migration, you don't have to do anything but asking on the right platform next time.

Comment: I posted here as I found some other questions about gpg. Sorry about that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm sorry I cannot tell you how to do it in Kleopatra, but it is rather easy on the command line.

1. If you haven't imported the private key yet, save it to a file (let's say, `key.pgp`, name and extension don't matter). Now run `gpg --import <key.pgp`. Your key should be listed using `gpg -K` now.
2. For setting trust (the highest trust level in OpenPGP is "ultimate", which is usually only applied to your own certificates, as you want to do in this case), run `gpg --edit-key [key-id]` (printed in `gpg -K` above). In the edit key menu, run `trust`; and enter <kbd>5</kbd> (followed by <kbd>Return</kbd> for "I trust ultimately". Confirm with <kbd>y</kbd> (again followed by <kbd>Return</kbd>), and finally run `save` to store the modified key and quit GnuPG.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
When I try to import the key saved into the file i get an error (translated from italian):

No valid OpenPGP data found

Total number of ‪analysed files: 0

Comment: If the answer resolved your issue, please consider selecting the checkmark on the left to mark the question as answered.

Comment: I think you read my message before I fully edited it. I didn't thought return here meant "send" like in a chat.

Comment: This sounds like serious trouble, and your private key file is messed up. Do you know how you created/exported it to KeePass?

Comment: I think we found the problem. I haven't exported the private key file BUT I have the key itself (my "password", if we can say it this way)

Comment: If you haven't got a backup of the private key, you lost it, and will not be able to recover it. If you've pregenerated a revocation certificate, you can at least [revoke the public key](http://askubuntu.com/questions/597750/how-to-revoke-old-openpgp-keys/597802#597802) (which seems to be stored in the key server network).

Comment: Mhhh, thanks.

I think I'll just create a new one :)

Comment: And remember to set up a reasonable backup (including more than just your private keys) and generating a revocation certificate.

Comment: Yep, it's strange indeed that I haven't been able to found any. I'm generally very accurate about data safety.
Thanks anyway

Comment: Kleopatra does _not_ store the keys, GnuPG does. Maybe you actually have the private keys in your backup, if you backed up the `~/.gnupg` folder.